# How to source Purchase Orders list in a field in Suitelet (suitescript 2.0)?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I need to source list of **Purchase Orders** in a SELECT field in my suitelet.

I tried this:

```
  var pos = form.addField({ // Purchase order select field
    id: 'custpage_selectpos',
    type: ui.FieldType.SELECT,
    label: 'Select PO',
    source: 'purchaseorder'
  });
```

After putting `purchaseorder` is the source property, all the transactions start being shown in my list field. Any idea how to only source the POs?

Comment: I managed to get this by having a custom select options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the filter first before creating the field

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4345782273.html#search.Operator